# Passing a lambda function to a template method

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, std-function

I have the following templated method:

```
auto clusters = std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<long>, math::Vector3f>>

template<class T> 
void eraserFunction(std::vector<T>& array, std::function<int(const T&, const T&)> func)
{
}
```

And I have a function that looks like

```
  auto comp1 = [&](
    const std::pair<std::vector<long>, math::Vector3f>& n1,
    const std::pair<std::vector<long>, math::Vector3f>& n2
  ) -> int  {
       return 0;
  };
  math::eraserFunction(clusters, comp1);
```

However, I get a syntax error saying:

```
  116 | void eraserFunction(std::vector<T>& array, std::function<int(const T&, const T&)> func)
      |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
core.hpp:116:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
geom.cpp:593:23: note:   'math::method(const at::Tensor&, const at::Tensor&, int, float, int, int, float)::<lambda(const std::pair<std::vector<long int>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1> >&, const std::pair<std::vector<long int>, Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1> >&)>' is not derived from 'std::function<int(const T&, const T&)>'
  593 |   math::eraserFunction(clusters, comp1);
```

Comment: How is `clusters` declared?

Comment: clusters is std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<long>, math::Vector3f>>

Comment: @raaj Your definition of `clusters` is wrong. Please make a [mre] so that we will get the same error you get without having to correct unrelated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function call tries to deduce `T` from both the first and second function parameter.

It will correctly deduce `T` from the first parameter, but fail to deduce it from the second parameter, because the second function argument is a lambda type, not a `std::function` type.

If deduction isn't possible from all parameters that are deduced context, deduction fails.

You don't really need deduction from the second parameter/argument here, since `T` should be fully determined by the first argument. So you can make the second parameter a non-deduced context, for example by using `std::type_identity`:

```
void eraserFunction(std::vector<T>& array, std::type_identity_t<std::function<int(const T&, const T&)>> func)
```

This requires C++20, but can be implemented easily in user code as well if you are limited to C++11:

```
template<typename T>
struct type_identity { using type = T; };
```

and then

```
void eraserFunction(std::vector<T>& array, typename type_identity<std::function<int(const T&, const T&)>>::type func)
```

`std::identity_type_t<T>` is a type alias for `std::identity_type<T>::type`. Everything left to the scope resolution operator `::` is a non-deduced context, which is why that works.

---

If you don't have any particular reason to use `std::function` here, you can also just take any callable type as second template argument:

```
template<class T, class F>
void eraserFunction(std::vector<T>& array, F func)
```

This can be called with a lambda, function pointer, `std::function`, etc. as argument. If the argument is not callable with the expected types, it will cause an error on instantiation of the function body containing the call. You can use SFINAE or since C++20 a type constraint to enforce this already at overload resolution time.